# Is it possible to display processed 14-bit Bayer images on iOS using UIImageView?

Tags: ios, image-processing, uiimageview, uiimage

I made a project to process Bayer pixels from RAW images on iOS.

I would like to display the processed pixels on the iOS screen, without having to first convert it to 8-bit RGBA (the format for UIImage), which is what UIImageView seems to only accept.

I reviewed CIRAWFilter and the sample RawExposeEmbedded project from Apple, to see how to possibly draw 14-bit data to screen, but the methods they use to render the image to screen involves GLKView and GL functions.

Is this the only known way to render 14-bit RAW processed pixels to an iOS screen or is there an alternative method, such as using CIImage/UIImage with UIImageView?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage?

Comment: I haven't heard of GPUImage by BradLarson; I'm taking a look at it now.